# How to find if number 2^n is in sum of 2^1 - 2^m

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's say that in some system users' statuses are assigned to a numbers that are a powers of 2.

```
 1 - New Member
 2 - Member
 4 - Friend
 8 - VIP
16 - Admin
32 - System Owner
```

So if `System Owner` got `Friend` and `Admin` statuses, his status will have a value of 52. Now, I want to query my status table and see what users have `Friend` status. How do I check that number `4` is a part of number-generating sum (`52`)?

If this is done by a function, following output expected:

```
isPartOf( 4, 52);   //returns true
isPartOf(12, 52);   //returns false since 8 (VIP) was not used during calculating 52
```

Algorithm that comes to my mind is subtraction of maximum possible number (2^n) that is lower than (in example case) `52`. Is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise AND.

```
>>> 52 & 4 == 4
True
>>> 52 & 12 == 12
False
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Or review your Computing 101 notes.

Comment: Wow, I completly forgot about binary representaion of numbers that consist of power-of-2 ones. Nice!